# How to reduce I/O Wait percentage in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I can see in MarkLogic 9 Monitoring History dashboard page at particular time say 1100 hrs, there is a spike in I/O wait more than 50% along with spike in Query traffic more than 800 MB/sec.
Is there a way to reduce I/O wait percentage?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think we'll need more information about MarkLogic's workload to offer anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

One of: too much i/o is required, or too little is available.  Or both.  It could be something doing a crazy amount of i/o.  If you can't figure it out by looking at access logs or monitoring history, a newer monitoring capability is http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/request_monitoring